# Bash Script: Remote SSH login until password request (pw MUST be manually entered)

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords

I haven't been been able to find any examples that are close enough to mine to be able to solve this problem.

I need to write a basic script that will ssh to a host, then ssh to another host, *but* the second host requires a password to be manually entered.

I don't need to automate passwords, simply to take care of typing the ssh commands themselves, the script can end at the point the second host asks for the password.

Due to the systems I am working with, no changes can be made to them.

I haven't been able to find a way to get the second ssh command to run while still allowing me to enter the password.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Here is the basic outline I have so far:

ssh server1 ssh -t -t -l user server2IP

The first server has keys set up so no details required.

Answer (score 1):

Ssh will only read a password from a TTY interface, so it won't prompt for a password when it doesn't have a tty. When you run ssh and specify a command to be run on the remote system, ssh doesn't allocate a TTY on the remote system unless you run it with the "-t" option.

Now, consider the command that you're running:

```
ssh server1 ssh -t -t -l user server2IP
```

On your local system, you're running `ssh` with a remote command and without "-t", so the process on server1 won't have a tty. The ssh instance on server1 doesn't have a tty, so it won't prompt for a password. You've specified that a tty be allocated on server2, but you're not running ssh there.

You need to request a tty for the ssh instance on server1:

```
ssh -t server1 ssh -t -t -l user server2IP
```

For this particular command, I don't think you need to specify "-t" for the second ssh instance, but it wouldn't hurt.